# Symfony Basic Translation Example

Tags: service, symfony, translation

I am new to Symfony2. Trying to establish translation Service. I am following the steps given in the official documentation. But not successful.

Following are steps followed

1. In 'symfony/app/config/config.yml' translation service by defining locale `"#translator:{ fallback: %locale% }"`
2. In `'symfony/app/config/parameters.yml'` defined locale parameter `"locale:de"`
3. In `'src/MyBundle/translateBundle/Resources/translations/messages.de.xlf'` is created

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
   <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
       <body>
           <trans-unit id="1">
               <source>Symfony2 is great</source>
               <target>J'aime Symfony2</target>
           </trans-unit>
       </body>
   </file>
   </xliff>
   ```

Now I hope with this coding now I should get: 'J'aime Symfony2' on execution of following code.

```
<?php

namespace MyDays\translateBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction() {
        $t = $this->get ( 'translator' )->trans ( 'Symfony2 is great' );        
        return new Response ( $t );
    }
}
```

But still getting original text as 'Symfony2 is great'!
Is there anything I have to do apart from the steps given in documentation?

Answer (score 8):

Have you removed `#` before `translator...` in `config.yml`?

Also you need to clear the cache after adding a new translation file.