# symfony translation - The "xlf" translation loader is not registered

Tags: symfony

I am doing a i18n testing on symfony2. (v2.4) .  And i follow the steps http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html.

Just like another guys' question [Symfony Basic Translation Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046460/symfony-basic-translation-example),  Exception i came across a exception "The "xlf" translation loader is not registered".

my config detail like this:

1. app/config/config.yml

   ```
     translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }  // locale=en
   ```
2. src/xxx/MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

> ```
> /**
>  *@Route("/tr")
>  */
> public function trAction()
> {
>     $translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('symfony.test.great');
>     return new Response($translated);
> }
> ```

3. src/xxx/MyBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.xlf (or with suffix “xliff”）

> ```
>        .....
>         <trans-unit id="10">
>             <source>symfony.test.great</source>
>             <target> Symfony is Great...</target>
>         </trans-unit>
>      ....
> ```

When i visit the router /tr, it says:

> The "xlf" translation loader is not registered. 500 Internal Server
>   Error - RuntimeException

Any wrong point? please give me a hand ,thanks in advance.

And more:
my compose.json :

> ```
> "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.3.3",
>     "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
>     "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
>     "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
>     "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
>     "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
>     "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
>     "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
>     "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
>     "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
>     "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
>     "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
>     "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.x",
>     "symfony/translation": "2.4.x-dev",
>     "symfony/config": "2.4.x",
> },
> ```

Comment: Try using "xliff" extension.

Comment: ```or with suffix “xliff”``` Seems he did already

Comment: yes。 i try three file formats. .xlf,  .xliff,  .yml . The first two file's content are same except the suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody.
I now can fix the issues by this: (add loader  manually)

in my Controller / action:

```
 /**
     *@Route("/tr")
     */
    public function trAction()
    {
        $tr = $this->get('translator');//->trans('symfony.test.great');
        $tr->addLoader('xliff', new XliffFileLoader());  // new add
        $tr->addLoader('xlf', new XliffFileLoader());    // new add 
        $translated = $tr->trans('symfony.test.great');
        return new Response($translated);
    }
```

I don't know why must to add this. And the symfony document "http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html" also don't add that. Any suggest will be welcome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but still someone might find it useful. Had the same problem which I solved by removing some packaged from composer.json

Remove these packages:

```
"symfony/translation": "2.3.*",
 "symfony/config": "2.3.*"
```

then run `composer update`

Symfony has built in translation so you don't need to add anything extra but still if you want or need to use them you probably need to add the extension to your twig environment. more info read the [docummentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#translation)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar problem like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader;
...
...
$translator = new Translator('en_US');
$translator->addLoader('xlf', new XliffFileLoader());
$translator->addResource('xlf', __DIR__ . '/registration.xlf', 'it_IT', 'registration');
```

Answer (score 0):

The loaders are configured in ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/translation.xml

You should have the following parameter:

```
<parameter key="translation.loader.xliff.class">Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader</parameter>
```

If everything looks ok, use xliff extension, check that your the file header looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

and clear the cache.

Comment: @pysome, it could be then that your file is not well formatted, validate here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: Thanks. I found the xliff loader in my file **./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/translation.xml** . And my xliff extension file's header just like you mentioned .`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>symfony.test.great</source>
                <target> Symfony is Great...</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
`

Comment: @pysome I don't know if this is the problem but `<file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">` should be `<file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages.xliff">` in your case, or leave `original` attribute blank.

Comment: I try the two  ways(keep original blank or set origianl="messages.xliff" ) . Unfortunately, the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just found the correct answer:

Search on your translation folder a file with the extension .xlf~  and delete it.

For example:
messages.en.xlf~

These files are created by the `translation:update` console command.