# Symfony 3.1 Yaml translation not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

I am trying to set translations for my Symfony 3.1 Project. I have added the following line to my `app/config/config.yml`:

```
translator: { fallback: en }
```

I have added a messages.en.yaml file in `app/Resources/translations/` with just one string:

```
firstname: Test
```

Now i am trying to access it on my twig file like :

```
<h1>{% trans %} firstname {% endtrans %}</h1>
```

I also tried to translate the string on DefaultController.php and the same error happens there as well:

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
....
$translatedMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('firstname');
var_dump($translatedMessage);
return $this->render('Default:index.html.twig');
```

When i try to access the page it gives me error like this:

> The "yaml" translation loader is not registered.

I have tried installing all the following packages into my project as well like:

```
composer require symfony/yaml
composer require symfony/translation
```

Please help. I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: do you have already see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541380/symfony-translation-the-xlf-translation-loader-is-not-registered?

Comment: yes i did look at that post. Thats regarding xlf. I tried to find the YAMLFileLoader parameter in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/translation.xml` and it exists. Also tried removing the `symfony/translation` and `symfony/config` packages from `composer.json` but still cannot load Yaml strings. There is no documentation regarding my error 'The `"yaml" translation loader is not registered.` ..

Comment: On github someone else has the same problem, but that is made by an other bundle, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1668